# Tesseract OCR - Handwritten data definition

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract, handwriting-recognition

I'm trying to do a handwritten character recognition using [Tesseract](http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/).
To do this, I need a handwritten (in english) data definition (to put in the tessdata directory):

```
  - tessdata/eng.freq-dawg
  - tessdata/eng.word-dawg
  - tessdata/eng.user-words
  - tessdata/eng.inttemp
  - tessdata/eng.normproto
  - tessdata/eng.pffmtable
  - tessdata/eng.unicharset
  - tessdata/eng.DangAmbigs
```

Where can I find these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are of the old 2.0x language data. Look for `tesseract-2.00.eng.tar.gz` in the [Download page](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list?num=100&start=100).